# oracle trunc date to minutes

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to truncate the date to the minute so I can be able to group it togheter.

```
SELECT to_char(SYSDATE,'mm-dd-yyyy hh:mi:ss')as date_min FROM dual
```

Is there way to do it in Oracle?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply `'mm-dd-yyyy hh:mi'`?

Comment: @Aleksej I thought of that. But I was thinking if there is a better way. Thanks

Comment: You have been provided with two solutions by Aleksej and A Horse but expressed dissatisfaction with both. So you need to **edit your question** to clarify exactly what problem you're trying to solve and what you mean by *"a better way"*. Posting some sample input data and expected results derived from that sample would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `trunc` with a second parameter:

```
select trunc(SYSDATE, 'mi') as date_min 
FROM dual
```

This way the data type (`DATE`) is kept which might be needed for other things

Comment: yes, but I need to get the hour and minutes.

Comment: @Mariana: but you wrote "*I need to truncate the date to the minute*" - the "truncated" date will work just fine for grouping

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be by

```
SELECT to_char(SYSDATE,'mm-dd-yyyy hh:mi')as date_min from dual
```

If you want to consider the different elements separately, you can use something like

```
select extract(month from systimestamp) as month,
       extract(day from systimestamp) as day,
       extract(year from systimestamp) as year,
       extract(hour from systimestamp) as hour,
       extract(minute from systimestamp) as minute
from dual
```

Notice that you need `systimestamp` here and not `sysdate`, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html#GUID-36E52BF8-945D-437D-9A3C-6860CABD210E) you find something more

Answer (score 0):

To group by time, regardless the day: `to_char(sysdate,'HH24:MI')`
where you put your date field in place of the 'sysdate'.

My tip is to describe what is your goal. Easier to see what you actually need. (ie. I want to see how the sales are coming in during the day, when do we get the most sales.)